# How can i refresh a captcha on click. I am using thytanium captcha for laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, laravel, captcha

I want to refresh the captcha, when i click the refresh link. Currently I am using the following code can someone suggest me what modification should I do in order to use refresh it.

```
<span id="capimg" style="margin-bottom: 20px; display: inline-block;">
<img src="{{URL::to('captcha')}}" onclick="this.src='{{URL::to('captcha')}}'" class="captcha">
</span>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('capimg').src='{{URL::to('captcha')}}'" class="m_tl">
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-3x"></i></a>
```

Comment: Is it google captcha ?

Comment: No it is not google captcha. It is thytanium captcha. https://github.com/thytanium/captcha here's the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <p>
  <img id='captcha_img' style='border: 1px solid #CBD8E5;' src='/captcha.php?img=<?=time();?>'/><br/>

  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha_img').src='captcha.php?img=' + Math.random(); return false">Reload Captcha</a> </p>
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was making a small mistake i was trying to change the span id instead of the img id. So I changed the code by giving a new id to img tag and then changing that, so it worked for me.